# how to write this query in sql-server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my table structure in sql-server:

```
id           Marks
----------   -----------
AAA          50
KKK          87
KKK          89
BBB          48
CCC          54
AAA          52
DDD          55
BBB          60
XXX          99
```

This is the desired output:

```
Name       attempts         Max Mark
-------    ----------------  ------------
AAA         2                 52
kkk         2                 89
BBB         2                 60
CCC         1                 54
DDD         1                 55
XXX         1                 99
```

I've tried this but it seems incorrect:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    count(*) as attempts,
    max(marks) 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY name, attempts, max_marks
```

Comment: Why do you say it's not correct?  Do you get incorrect results?  What are the incorrect results you get?

Comment: You should group by `id` instead

Comment: you should not have your aggregated fields in your group by statement

Comment: Think two seconds: you are trying to group by the results of the aggregate functions! and that is wrong! Only group by `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track just added too much to grouping field,

```
SELECT id AS name
       ,COUNT(*) AS Attempts
       ,MAX(marks) as MaxMarks
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY id
```

If your column is already part of aggregate function such as `MAX` or `COUNT` it does not need to be included in `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    id AS Name,
    count(id) AS attempts,
    max(Marks) AS Max_Mark
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY id
```